# how to implement a WebApi authorisation that will return only user's data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I am building a WebApi project where we have to go beyond the simple role authorization. 
Basically, the user logged in should only view the data he / she has created. Data could be images, posts, documents and more. 
I had a look at claims from WIF, but i dont seem to understand how i can used them to implement this sort of authorization. All implementations I have seen almost exclusively focus on action authorizations and do not touch the data access part.
I have the feeling that this is a common problem for all APIs out there.
How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple

- Find out the Logged-in user (get the user Principal attached to the request/thread)
- Use the User's ID to filter any data requests your API is making (pass the user ID as a parameter to your data queries

Comment: How do you consider roles in this implementation? There will be lots of duplicate code in my services.

Comment: You did not explain what does the 'roles' do in the data filtering question?

Comment: The roles help determine the authorization logic for each logic.